# Pandas: compare prices if the timestamp format is the same (for loop)

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
              time      mid price
0   2019-03-13 14:45:00 0.002037
1   2019-03-13 14:49:00 0.002038
2   2019-03-13 14:50:00 0.002048
3   2019-03-13 14:51:00 0.002051
4   2019-03-14 07:49:00 0.001986
5   2019-03-14 07:50:00 0.001973
6   2019-03-14 07:51:00 0.001973
7   2019-03-14 11:35:00 0.001972
8   2019-03-14 11:41:00 0.001968
9   2019-03-14 11:50:00 0.001970
10  2019-03-14 11:59:00 0.001972
```

What I need to do is to compare the first price of the hour with the last one. So in my my example, it would be take the first price at `2019-03-13 14:45:00` `0.002037` and compare it with the last one which is at `2019-03-13 14:51:00` `0.002051`, and add a new column to my dataframe like that:

```
movement_price = price2 - price1

df_uptrend.at[index, 'price_movement'] = np.fabs(movement_price)
```

What I tried so far is the following:

```
for index, row  in islice(df_uptrend.iterrows(), 0, 42):    

  if df_uptrend.loc[index, 'time'].strftime('%H') == df_uptrend.loc[index +1, 'time'].strftime('%H'):
      match= True
      price1 = row['mid price']
      time1 = df_uptrend.loc[index, 'time']
      continue
  if match and df_uptrend.loc[index, 'time'].strftime('%H') !=df_uptrend.loc[index +1, 'time'].strftime('%H'):
      price2 = df_uptrend.loc[index, 'mid price']
      time2 = df_uptrend.loc[index, 'time']

      movement_time = time2 - time1
      movement_price = price2 - price1

      df_uptrend.at[index, 'price_movement'] = np.fabs(movement_price)
      df_uptrend.at[index, 'time_movement'] = movement_time
```

But it compares the price at the of the hour with the one right before... any idea on how to fix that? thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand, for the column `price_movement`, at which row you want the difference, at the last one per hour? with your example it would be where the time is `2019-03-13 14:51:00`?

Comment: Hi @Ben.T, yes indeed, at the last one per hour.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) function, which could allow you to resample your dataframe by hours. Then use [first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html) and [last](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last.html) method to extract first and last value of the hour and. Then just subtract the two.

Something like this should do the trick :

```
df['price_movement'] = df.resample('60T', on='time').last() - df.resample('60T', on='time').first()
```

This will result in a value of 0 if there is only one value for one hour